# Angular $update resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

**EDIT: If it's difficult to troubleshoot without me posting more code, let me know and I can add more to the question.**

---

I have two instances of basically the same code, and one of them is working while the other isn't.

**Working fine:**

```
$scope.update = function() {
  var question = $scope.question;
  question.$update(function() {
    $location.path('questions/' + question._id);
  });
};
```

**Not working:**

```
$scope.updateAnswer = function() {
  var answer = $scope.answerEdited;
  answer.$update(function() {
    $location.path('questions/' + $routeParams.questionId);
  });

  $scope.toggleEditAnswer(answer);
};
```

I get the error: *undefined is not a function* at my `$update` function.  Here's my resource:

```
angular.module('intquestApp')
  .factory('Answers', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/answers/:answerId', {
      answerId: '@_id'
    }, {
      update: {
        method: 'PUT'
      }
    });
  });
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?  If I understand the flow correctly, the `answer.$update` uses the resource somehow?  Also, if I use `console.log` to view what `answer` is being updated, it is the correct one:

```
Resource {_id: "543d8896039390eb5e000001", created: "2014-10-14T20:33:26.514Z", creator: Object, questionid: "543d8693994fc1685d000001", __v: 0…}
```

How exactly can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What is `$scope.answerEdited`?

Comment: The answer currently being edited.  It equals the Resource element returned in the console.log, so it seems like it has the correct data and everything

Comment: Have you defined answer in madal i.e schema with proper type?

Comment: Does `answer` have any other methods available to it? Does `$scope.answerEdited.$update` have the same error?

Comment: Does not work for `$scope.answerEdited`, same error.  `answer` has a `$save` function that works fine.

Comment: What _line_ is throwing the error? `answer.$update(function() {`?

Comment: The line: `answer.$update...`

Comment: The console log does not show object states at the moment you log them, but at the moment you view them. It is possible then that `$scope.answerEdited` is indeed undefined when you try to call it's `$update` method. Put a breakpoint on that line and see what it really is.

Comment: or did you forgot to inject Answers in controller?? like angular.module('intquestApp').controller('intquestAppController', ['$scope', '$stateParams','$compile', '$location','Answers' , 
 function($scope, $stateParams, $compile, $location, Answers) { // code

Comment: No I have Answers in the controller.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I placed a breakpoint on the line, and simplified my code by taking out the useless assignment `answer = $scope.answerEdited` and just changed it to `$scope.answerEdited.$update...`  Through debugger it looks like the correct Resource is being held...

Comment: Then something else is happening in some code you have not shown us.

Comment: Are you sure $scope.answerEdited is an instance of Answers? You can try to modify your code adding a wrapper around it like this ```var answer = new Answers($scope.answerEdited);``` and then try to run ```answer.$update```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try the following and check if it works?

```
$scope.updateAnswer = function() {
    Answers.update($scope.answerEdited, function(response) {
        $location.path('questions/' + $routeParams.questionId);
    });

    $scope.toggleEditAnswer(answer);
};
```